# Logging stopped working after upgrading to Magento CE 1.9

Tags: upgrade, ce-1.9.2.4, logging

After upgrading Magento CE to version 1.9.2.4, it stopped writing to `log_url` and `log_url_info` tables.

When I connect directly to mySQL database and make a `SELECT` query to `log_url` ordering by `visit_time`, the last record I get is about the time just before the upgrade.

At the same time I can see new records in other tables like `log_visitor` and `log_visitor_info`, so the logging seems to work only partially.

**Questions:**

1. Has anyone else experienced this after upgrading to CE 1.9 ?
2. Maybe the tables have been deprecated and are not used by Magento anymore? I could not find any official documentation on this.

I was able to reproduce this issue on my development scenario as well (just upgrade Magento CE from 1.7 to 1.9).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for answering my own question, but I found the cause of such behaviour.

In Magento CE 1.9 they added new setting for controlling the logs: `Enable Log` with values `Yes`, `No` and `Visitors Only`.
In CE 1.7 it did not exist.

The default value of this setting applied after Magento upgrade is `Visitors Only` which causes that logs are saved to `log_visitor` and `log_visitor_info` but other log tables like `log_url`, `log_url_info` and `log_customer` are empty.

After switching `Enable Log` to `Yes`, the logs are saved to all the mentioned tables.